# unmatched square bracket Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am sure to have done some search, and I am not a complete novice in regexes (say, I use them regularly, not pun intended, in `vim`). Let's say I have a path `/home/myself/input.txt` and
I would like to extract `input.txt`. What can be easier, right.
So, here is my Perl line (and I am indeed new to Perl):

```
my $s = "/home/myself/input.txt";
if ( $s =~ /^.*([^/]+)$/ ) { # match anything except a slash...
    my $in = "$1"; #extract the first group
}
```

However, the terminal is not happy:

> Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in

What am I missing in such a simple situation? Doe square brackets have some other meaning in Perl?

Comment: `my $s = '/home/myself/input.txt'; if ( not $s ) { print "empty string"; } else { (my $in) = $s =~ /([^\/]+)$/; print $in; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is wrong, that's very simple.

The delimiter is `/`, so your regex should looks like :

```
 /^.*([^\/]+)$/
 #      ^  backslash is mandatory with / delimiter
```

Another solution, using [`m//` *match operator*](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) and an *arbitrary `!` delimiter* :

```
m!^.*([^/]+)$!
```

Comment: Ohhh I am sure to have read this. The slash is used both for matching and delimiting, what a stupid mistake. Thanks, it works.

Comment: with !, you no longer need the \

Comment: Sure, simple copy/paste and forgot to remove it, thanks